# How to make scrollviewer scroll pixels not components (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I'm trying to make my scroll viewer scroll flawlessly, that is I have a scrollviewer and it contains a stackpanel , the stack panel contains a user-made user control. and they can increase or decrease dynamically at run time.

the problem is, suppose i have only 2 user controls in my stack panel , the scroll viewer have only 2 levels of scrolling, so it scrolls a whole user control for each click or mouse-wheel movement.

how can I change that? is it a property or there is a mistake in the design?

here is the xaml code for it:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="420" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="862" Margin="0,0,-2,0" CanContentScroll="True" PanningRatio="0.1">
                <StackPanel x:Name="hpList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="843"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

and the stack panel expands or shrinks dynamically.

Comment: Set CanContentScroll="False" and it will work magically.

Comment: now it can't scroll at all!

Comment: in addiotion to @devhedgehog  now Try setting StackPanel with IsItemsHost="False"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set CanContentScroll="False" and remove the stackpanel height\width

Comment: that did the trick! thanks , but can u explain what does the height\width has to do with it?

Comment: the stackpanel size go to the scroll content size so it seems to scrollviewer that he need no scroll, (if i'm unclear google is full of answers :) )