# Implementing control by control (not smooth) scrolling panel

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, panel

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` that contains `User Controls` from up to down with vertical scrollbar.

Like any other scrollable control, I can scroll it pixel by pixel.

Is there a way (.NET Framework or native API way) to scroll it `User Control` by `User Control`, in order to snap to next or previous `User Control`? They can have different height.

I would like to reproduce `DataGridView` or *Excel/Calc* row by row scrolling type.

Comment: If you know the necessary amount, can't you add it to the `VerticalScroll.Value` (or `HorizontalScroll.Value `)?

Comment: I could. The problem is how to prevent panel to scroll between two controls when user is using the mouse to scroll the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution.

Set `AutoScroll=false`, add a `VScrollBar`, and put the following code:

```
vScrollBar1.Maximum = MyList.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
vScrollBar1.SmallChange = MyList.VerticalScroll.SmallChange;
vScrollBar1.LargeChange = MyList.VerticalScroll.LargeChange;
vScrollBar1.Scroll += (sender, args) =>
{
    switch (args.Type)
    {
        case ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack:

            var sum = 0;
            Control prevCtrl = null;

            foreach (Control control in MyList.Controls)
            {
                if (prevCtrl == null || control.Bottom > prevCtrl.Bottom)
                {
                    if (args.OldValue >= sum && args.OldValue < sum + control.Height)
                    {
                        MyList.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, sum);
                    }

                    sum += control.Height;
                }

                prevCtrl = control;
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I this question - [How to make scrollviewer scroll pixels not components (wpf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701831/how-to-make-scrollviewer-scroll-pixels-not-components-wpf), the behavior you expect is unwanted. Thus, you could do what the user has done in the described question.

The essential difference between your question and the one referenced is to do with host control. You have used `FlowLayoutPanel` and in the referenced question `StackPanel` is used.

So, if by any chance your application is a WPF application can you change it to `StackPanel`?

Did setting these properties `AutoScroll=True` with `WrapContent=True` on FlowLayoutPanel not work?

Comment: I don't plan to use WPF (hosted control) for now, unless there is no other solution.

Comment: `AutoScroll=true` and `WrapContent=false`, in order to make a list of controls.