# How to stop the behavior of Scroll viewer auto scrolling to visibility in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a scroll viewer in the grid and it has a combo box (Just sample for my problem) inside of it.

When the combo box is partially visible on the scroll viewer and when i click it auto scroll to the visibility (I put combo box just for reference - facing issue with other controls as well)

I need to stop this behavior and pretty confused about it.
Refer the following images

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Set CanContentScroll="False" as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701831/how-to-make-scrollviewer-scroll-pixels-not-components-wpf?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer,
It was very tricky.

There is an event in WPF control called

```
RequestBringIntoView
```

This will fire default when the control is loaded and all we have to do is setting

```
e.handled= true
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

set CanContentScroll="False" ....